# Unable to find DateTool

Tags: c#, velocity, nvelocity

in Java velocity, in order to format dates I just add the date tool to the context
e.g.

```
context.add("date", new DateTool());
```

and then inside the template

```
$date.format('EEE, MMM d, yyyy at ha', $myDate)
```

but in NVelocity I am unable to find the DateTool, it doesnt seem to be part of the library.

Comment: I changed your title to be a little more descriptive.

Comment: You should be able to call `.ToString("...")` on any `System.DateTime`.

Comment: didnt think i could do that in the template. works nicely

Comment: I should have posted that as an answer rather than a comment, done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `.ToString("...")` on any `System.DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

a search for anything mentioning ["date" in http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net](https://www.google.com/search?q=date%20site:nvelocity.sourceforge.net) yields:

http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/api/NVelocity/App/Tools/VelocityFormatter.html

and

http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/api/NVelocity/SupportClass.html

you might want to reference the following post:

- [Making Simple Things Hard: NVelocity](http://www.tigraine.at/2009/07/14/making-simple-things-hard-nvelocity)

Refer the above link and make simple thing like below in .vm template,

```
#set ($recordDate = $RecordCreationDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") )
<div> $recordDate </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but didnt really answer why there isn't a DateTool, but it is a nudge in the right directuion. thanks

Comment: @Crudler as per  Daniel Hölbling's and Jonathon Rossi's answer you can use .ToString("...") :)